# tkinter notepad program trying to make a right click copy paste option really new to this can't get this to work

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a basic notepad program that you can save stuff with but I want when you right click after highlighting something I want to be able to copy / paste.

I haven't tried much not sure how to do this.

Python code(notepad)

```
import tkinter 
import os     
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

class Notepad: 
    __root = Tk()

# default window width and height 
__thisWidth = 300
__thisHeight = 300
__thisTextArea = Text(__root) 
__thisMenuBar = Menu(__root) 
__thisFileMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0) 
__thisEditMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0) 
__thisHelpMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0) 

# To add scrollbar 
__thisScrollBar = Scrollbar(__thisTextArea)      
__file = None

def __init__(self,**kwargs): 

    # Set icon 
    try: 
            self.__root.wm_iconbitmap("Notepad.ico")  
    except: 
            pass

    # Set window size (the default is 300x300) 

    try: 
        self.__thisWidth = kwargs['width'] 
    except KeyError: 
        pass

    try: 
        self.__thisHeight = kwargs['height'] 
    except KeyError: 
        pass

    # Set the window text 
    self.__root.title("Untitled - Notepad") 

    # Center the window 
    screenWidth = self.__root.winfo_screenwidth() 
    screenHeight = self.__root.winfo_screenheight() 

    # For left-align 
    left = (screenWidth / 2) - (self.__thisWidth / 2)  

    # For right-align 
    top = (screenHeight / 2) - (self.__thisHeight /2)  

    # For top and bottom 
    self.__root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.__thisWidth, 
                                          self.__thisHeight, 
                                          left, top))  

    # To make the textarea auto resizable 
    self.__root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    self.__root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 

    # Add controls (widget) 
    self.__thisTextArea.grid(sticky = N + E + S + W) 

    # To open new file 
    self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="New", 
                                    command=self.__newFile)     

    # To open a already existing file 
    self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Open", 
                                    command=self.__openFile) 

    # To save current file 
    self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Save", 
                                    command=self.__saveFile)     

    # To create a line in the dialog         
    self.__thisFileMenu.add_separator()                                          
    self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", 
                                    command=self.__quitApplication) 
    self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="File", 
                                   menu=self.__thisFileMenu)      

    # To give a feature of cut  
    self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Cut", 
                                    command=self.__cut)              

    # to give a feature of copy     
    self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Copy", 
                                    command=self.__copy)          

    # To give a feature of paste 
    self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Paste", 
                                    command=self.__paste)          

    # To give a feature of editing 
    self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Edit", 
                                   menu=self.__thisEditMenu)      

    # To create a feature of description of the notepad 
    self.__thisHelpMenu.add_command(label="About Notepad", 
                                    command=self.__showAbout)  
    self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Help", 
                                   menu=self.__thisHelpMenu) 

    self.__root.config(menu=self.__thisMenuBar) 

    self.__thisScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)                     

    # Scrollbar will adjust automatically according to the content         
    self.__thisScrollBar.config(command=self.__thisTextArea.yview)      
    self.__thisTextArea.config(yscrollcommand=self.__thisScrollBar.set) 


def __quitApplication(self): 
    self.__root.destroy() 
    # exit() 

def __showAbout(self): 
    showinfo("Notepad","Mrinal Verma") 

def __openFile(self): 

    self.__file = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", 
                                  filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"), 
                                    ("Text Documents","*.txt")]) 

    if self.__file == "": 

        # no file to open 
        self.__file = None
    else: 

        # Try to open the file 
        # set the window title 
        self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad") 
        self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0,END) 

        file = open(self.__file,"r") 

        self.__thisTextArea.insert(1.0,file.read()) 

        file.close() 







def __newFile(self): 
    self.__root.title("Untitled - Notepad") 
    self.__file = None
    self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0,END) 

def __saveFile(self): 

    if self.__file == None: 
        # Save as new file 
        self.__file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt', 
                                        defaultextension=".txt", 
                                        filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"), 
                                            ("Text Documents","*.txt")]) 

        if self.__file == "": 
            self.__file = None
        else: 

            # Try to save the file 
            file = open(self.__file,"w") 
            file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0,END)) 
            file.close() 

            # Change the window title 
            self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad") 


    else: 
        file = open(self.__file,"w") 
        file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0,END)) 
        file.close() 

def __cut(self): 
    self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Cut>>") 

def __copy(self): 
    self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Copy>>") 

def __paste(self): 
    self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Paste>>") 

def run(self): 

    # Run main application 
    self.__root.mainloop() 







# Run main application 
notepad = Notepad(width=600,height=400) 
notepad.run()
```

What I thought would work

```
w = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu", width=40, height=20)
w.pack()

# create a menu
popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
popup.add_command(label="Next") # , command=next) etc...
popup.add_command(label="Previous")
popup.add_separator()
popup.add_command(label="Home")

def do_popup(event):
# display the popup menu
try:
    popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
finally:
    # make sure to release the grab (Tk 8.0a1 only)
    popup.grab_release()

w.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)

b = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
 b.pack()
```

I expect when u right click after highlighting that you can copy paste. At the moment there is no right click menu or function for copying/ pasting. u can remove the tab on the top for copy paste if it can be put in a right click popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correct answer was given by Henry Yik.

A complete version of Notepad with right click is given below. I have taken the liberty to refactor the program to make it more [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compatible, mostly concerning variable names, not using wildcard imports (*) and removing some comments as code is self descriptive.

```
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Menu, Scrollbar, N, S, E, W, RIGHT, Y, END
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename, askopenfilename


class RightClicker:
    def __init__(self, event):
        right_click_menu = Menu(None, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)

        for txt in ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste']:
            right_click_menu.add_command(
                label=txt, command=lambda event=event, text=txt:
                self.right_click_command(event, text))

        right_click_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root + 40, event.y_root + 10, entry='0')

    def right_click_command(self, event, cmd):
        event.widget.event_generate(f'<<{cmd}>>')


class Notepad:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.file_name = None
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Untitled - Notepad")
        self.text_area = Text(self.root)

        menu_bar = Menu(self.root)
        file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        edit_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        help_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.root.config(menu=menu_bar)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.text_area)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.text_area.yview)
        self.text_area.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        self.text_area.bind('<Button-3>', RightClicker)

        # set icon and window size (default is 300 x 300)
        try:
            self.root.wm_iconbitmap("Notepad.ico")
        except:   #pylint: disable=W0702
            pass

        try:
            width = kwargs['width']
        except KeyError:
            width = 300

        try:
            height = kwargs['height']
        except KeyError:
            height = 300

        # place notepad in the center of the screen
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        left = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
        top = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, left, top))

        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.text_area.grid(sticky=N + E + S + W)

        # file menu controls
        file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.new_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.open_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_file)
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.quit_application)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

        # edit menu controls
        edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut", command=self.cut_text)
        edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy", command=self.copy_text)
        edit_menu.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.paste_text)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)

        # help menu controls
        help_menu.add_command(label="About Notepad", command=self.show_about)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help_menu)

    def quit_application(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def show_about(self):
        showinfo("Notepad", "Mrinal Verma")

    def open_file(self):
        self.file_name = askopenfilename(
            defaultextension=".txt",
            filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"), ("Text Documents", "*.txt")])

        if self.file_name == "":
            self.file_name = None

        else:
            self.root.title(os.path.basename(self.file_name) + " - Notepad")
            self.text_area.delete(1.0, END)

            with open(self.file_name, 'r') as file:
                self.text_area.insert(1.0, file.read())

    def new_file(self):
        self.root.title("Untitled - Notepad")
        self.file_name = None
        self.text_area.delete(1.0, END)

    def save_file(self):
        if self.file_name is None:
            self.file_name = asksaveasfilename(
                initialfile='Untitled.txt', defaultextension=".txt",
                filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"), ("Text Documents", "*.txt")])

            if self.file_name == "":
                self.file_name = None

            else:
                with open(self.file_name, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(self.text_area.get(1.0, END))

                self.root.title(os.path.basename(self.file_name) + " - Notepad")

        else:
            with open(self.file_name, 'w') as file:
                file.write(self.text_area.get(1.0, END))

    def cut_text(self):
        self.text_area.event_generate("<<Cut>>")

    def copy_text(self):
        self.text_area.event_generate("<<Copy>>")

    def paste_text(self):
        self.text_area.event_generate("<<Paste>>")

    def run_notepad(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


def main():
    notepad = Notepad(width=600, height=400)
    notepad.run_notepad()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you so much. i did a python class a while ago and i found this part of it so interesting. you can do so much with tkinter. python idle( didnt know this till recently) was made completely with tkinter.

Comment: im sure theres ways to do these exact same things in javascript/ etc but for now i got this down not till this past month did i know how to save stuff to places on your pc.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't bind `<Button-3>` to your `Text` widget.

Simply add the below to your class constructor:

```
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    ...
    self.__thisTextArea.bind("<Button-3>",lambda e: self.__thisMenuBar.tk_popup(e.x_root + 40, e.y_root + 10, entry="0"))
```

But generally I recommend making a rightclicker class instead, and apply to any widgets you want, like so:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class RightClicker:
    def __init__(self, e):
        commands = ["Cut","Copy","Paste"]
        menu = tk.Menu(None, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)

        for txt in commands:
            menu.add_command(label=txt, command=lambda e=e,txt=txt:self.click_command(e,txt))

        menu.tk_popup(e.x_root + 40, e.y_root + 10, entry="0")

    def click_command(self, e, cmd):
        e.widget.event_generate(f'<<{cmd}>>')

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
text.bind("<Button-3>", RightClicker)
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.bind("<Button-3>", RightClicker)
root.mainloop()
```